# Rails time type and time zones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I have a Rails app that stores time values, and I have set a time zone in config/application.rb.

This works correctly on datetime columns, but time columns show the time in UTC, not the specified time zone.

The time on these two examples are both stored as 20:50 (UTC) in the database, but when I show it in a view the time column shows as UTC and the datetime column is correctly shown in the chosen time zone.

```
time2:     2000-01-01 20:50:00 UTC
datetime2: 2012-02-09 21:50:00 +0100
```

Is this expected behavior? Shouldn't time types also use the configured time zone?

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord uses [TimeWithZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html), where methods like `localtime`, `utc`, `utc?` may help you.

Comment: So if an attribute is of type time, it doesn't automatically convert to the configured time zone in the view, but you must write something like <%= u.time2.localtime %>? But attributes of datetime gets automatically converted and you can just type <%= u.datetime2 %>. Why the difference of the two types?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is expected behavior. Rails (ActiveRecord) stores times in UTC, then coverts them to whatever time zone `Time.zone` is set to upon rendering in the view.

Comment: Yes, I know that, as I said in the question, I have set a time zone and both the two examples above are stored in the database in UTC (20:50), but when shown in a view, only the datetime attribute gets converted to the time zone. Doesn't ActiveRecord convert time attributes? Just datetime attributes?

Comment: Well, a date shouldn't (wouldn't) have a time zone associated with it really. Only time or datetime. So yes, that makes sense.

Comment: I have not mentioned anything about date, just time and datetime. Once again, as I said in the question, I have configured a time zone and I have one time and one datetime stored as UTC in the database, but when I show them in a view like this: <%= u.time2 %> and <%= u.datetime2 %> just the datetime attribute gets converted to the time zone.

Answer (score 0):

I give up this, Rails seems to totally ignore config.time_zone with time attributes and just uses it for datetime attributes for reasons I don't understand. And as it seems, not many others understand it as well.

I will change the time attributes to type string and parse it to a time object when I need to work with it as a time object. If this is fixed in a later Rails release I can always change back to using time attributes, but now I need to go on, this has been holding me back for days.

But thanks for trying to help :)